# Entering foreign characters in a text box

Tags: html, internationalization, textbox, virtual-keyboard

In Windows 7, you can configure keyboards so that you can type in different languages. To switch "virtual" keyboards, you have to click the little icon in the task bar and select the language in which you want to type.

I have two text boxes on a page, one is for typing English letters and the other is for typing Korean Hangul and Hanja. I would like users to be able to click into one, type English, and click in the other and type Korean without having to switch keyboards in the task bar (or optimally without even having alternate keyboards set up). The user will be switching languages often, so it will be highly inconvenient to have to switch manually every time.

Is there a way to specify for a certain textbox that you want the keyboard for that textbox to be a specific one?

Comment: If I understand your problem, you have HTML page served from web browser and you want to switch input method (not just keyboard layout) automatically? Or is your application client-side with HTML UI?

Comment: @Pawel yes it's just a web page the user will load from their hard drive.

Comment: If this is local, I would recommend to write simple Winforms application. Switching keyboard layouts in Winforms is peace of cake. HTML does not have the support for it :/

Comment: @Pawel no, I need it to be HTML because it will run on different platforms than just windows. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory there is a CSS property called ime-mode which should let you control the behavior of `input` tags:

```
<input id="english" style="ime-mode: disabled">
<input id="korean" style="ime-mode: active">
```

The problem is, browser support is very limited (at least that is what [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/ime-mode)) and it might not just work for certain web browser/Operating System combinations (i.e. won't run on Linux).

Comment: I don't see how this sets the input to be Korean though. I don't think `ime-mode` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Seth: This won't set IME mode to Korean. This needs to be done by end user (that could be activated by the key stroke if you assign it). However, my understanding is Korean users would have that enabled. What it does, it disables the support for the text box where English is required.